# Multiplicative Inverse in a $256$ Galois Field

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I am working on finding the multiplicative reverse in $GF(2^8)$ using the Euclidean Algorithm but after reading multiple sources, I feel as though I am proceeding incorrectly. Using the irreducible polynomial $m(p)=x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1=0x11B$ I am trying to find the inverse of $x^6+x^4+x+1=0x53$

I know using long division (via http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f396eaca9aaccbf858652bccc972324a) I get for the first step
$$(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)=(x^6+x^4+x+1)*(x^2-1)+(2x^4-x^2+2x+2)$$
but do I keep the negatives and even coefficients? I can't seem to get a reasonable answer and all the examples I have seen use simpler numbers. I know the answer to be $x^7+x^6+x^3+x=0xCA$ I just cannot seem to get there.

Comment: Your coefficients are modulo $2$, so $2 = 0$ and $-1 = 1$.

Comment: To expand on @Andreas' comment: $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1=(x^6+x^4+x+1)(x^2+1)+x^2$.

Comment: Well at least I was on the right track. I am still a little confused then since that means $(x^6+x^4+x+1 )=(x^2)*(x^4 )+(x^4+x+1)$ but that would mean $(x^2)=(x^4+x+1)*(a)+(r)$ and then I am working with fractional exponents. I must be missing something because I should be getting a remainder of 1 at some point.

Comment: Recall that the remainder (if non-zero) must have degree smaller that the divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you should obtain.

\begin{align}
&x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1 = (x^6+x^4+x_1+1) (x^2 + 1) + x^2\\
&x^6+x^4+x+1 = x^2 (x^4 + x^2) + x + 1\\
&x^2 = (x+1) x + 1.
\end{align}

Comment: Ah, I have stared at this for a while but now it just slapped me across the face. Long division almost defeated me, of all things.