# How to calculate the irreducible polynomial in galois field

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I have a an expression `(x^3 + x^2 + 1) / (x^6 + x^5) in GF(2^8)` and its primitive polynomials `(0,1,3,4,8)`

How to deal with this equation and what is the logic behind this?

Comment: Any finite field larger than $GF(p)$ needs a construction. I suppose the computer scientists have a standard construction for $GF(256)$, but readers of this site probably don’t know it. (I don’t) And you need to explain the notation (0,1,3,4,8).

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `(0,1,3,4,8)` refers to the irreducible polynomial $1+x+x^3+x^4+x^8$.

Comment: Too bad you don't use $1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^8$. For then you could use a discrete logarithm table like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1067963/11619) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1843177/11619). Anyway, if this is for a piece of software I would not consider anything but a discrete log table.

Comment: For a worked example your version of $GF(256)$ take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1628274/11619).

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2408354/11619). and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/529156/11619).

Comment: Thanks jyrki , that helps !!